# Custom hook that only returns helper functions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, react-hooks, functional-programming

I made a custom hook that only returns helper functions. Nowhere in the custom hook do I use another hook (useState, useEffect...)

Example:

```js
import backend from '../lib/backend';
import axios, { AxiosError } from 'axios';

interface PresignedData {
  fields: any;
  url: string;
  key: string;
}

type Resource = 'users' | 'events';

function useBucket() {
  const uploadViaPresignedPost = async function (
    resource: Resource,
    file: File
  ) {
    ...
  };

  const buildImageUrl = function (key: string) {
    return `${process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_S3_BUCKET_DOMAIN}/${key}`;
  };
  return { uploadViaPresignedPost, buildImageUrl };
}
export default useBucket;
```

Is this common practice? Or would it be better to create a class with static methods? export helper functions from separate file? What is best practice?

Comment: What do you gain using a React hook to return utility functions over just a normal export/import? Not much, if anything IMO. You certainly are now restricted in where you can access them since the hook that returns them ***can only*** be called from a React function component or another custom hook. Seems less than ideal.

Comment: Yeah, this is the best way. But as someone said, it's easier to add state logic to it in the future if needed. I'll probably split them into files, though

Comment: In that case I'd recommend just creating separate custom React hooks instead, exporting/importing them similarly to utility functions.

Answer (score 2):

Using a class for this wouldn't make all that much sense because a class is meant for when you need to tie together *data* associated with an instance with *methods* that can operate on that data. If there's no data associated with an instance - if the class never has `new` called on it - then there's not much point to a class in the first place. A few plain functions or a plain object with functions in it would make more sense than a class.

Your current approach of a custom hook that doesn't use any other hooks inside it seems a bit weird, but it's not forbidden. Feel free to use that approach if you want. Using a custom hook has an added benefit that *if* you later decide to change the logic and, for example, feel the desire to add a `useState` or `useEffect` or something to the custom hook, it's trivial to add them into the custom hook. In contrast, if you used anything other than a custom hook and later found that you needed to add something that required hook logic, you would not be able to without first refactoring everything back into a custom hook again.

Comment: Class with static methods is sometimes used as a repo for database. You would never call the `new` keyword on it. But yeah, it doesn't seem right to use a class